# how to iterate over rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get a object value in javascript from rows by

router.get('/mapstrial', function (req, res) {

```
client.connect(function(err){
    });
client.execute('SELECT * FROM data.test;', function (err, result) {
var count= result.rows.length;
var user = [];
for( var i=1; i<= count; i++)
{ user[i] = result.rows[0].sensor;
console.log("here is the sensor", user[i]);
 }; 

console.log("result=", result);
console.log("count=", result.rows.length)
res.render('mapstrial',{"jsresult":result,
                     "rowcount":count
                           });
}); 
    });
```

this outputs correctly. I get value for sensor(loops 6 times) and count like '6' and '7'

But what I want is to iterate over rows using a loop. so when I change my code to say

```
for( var i=1; i<= count; i++)
**{ user[i] = result.rows[i].sensor;**
console.log("here is the sensor", user[i]);
 };
```

it is throwing me an error like cannot read property sensor of undefined.

Comment: is `count` equal to or less than the number of rows?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume the result in the callback uses zero based index (your working example where you use rows[0] also suggests this). So your loop should be

```
for (var i=0; i < count; i++) { 
  user[i] = result.rows[i].sensor;
  console.log("here is the sensor", user[i]);
};
```